How to create and asign a AWS role to create ECS by using terraform?
I have an existing admin role in AWS, and I use it to perform terraform:
# main.tf
provider "aws" {
  ...
  ...
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "xxx"
  }
  ...
  ...
}

Now I want to create a new role to be my ECS's execution_role_arn:
# myProject.tf
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xxxx" {
    ...
    ...
    execution_role_arn = "new role xxxx"
    ...
    ...
}

I'm a newbie on AWS and Terraform. Please tell me how to create it in my role.tf, and how to write a policy for the new role, and how to use the no role to create ECS, thank you.
I'm writing code to create a role in terraform, but it only works the first time, after that it prompts for a duplicate role.

│ Error: updating ECS Service : InvalidParameterException: The service couldn't be updated because a valid taskRoleArn is not being used. Specify a valid task role in your task definition and try again.

We don't know what role.tf has inside. Would you mind adding that to the question as well?

If you are wondering how to create an AWS resource like an IAM role using Terraform, you should start by looking at the documentation for that resource type in the Terraform AWS provider's documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role

The below code is to create a new role with policy. You can replace the policy as JSON content with the Role policy's JSON.
role.tf
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_role.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
              "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
              "ecr:BatchGetImage",
              "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

Then change the execution_role_arn argument in the task definition block and Run the terraform script.
# myProject.tf
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xxxx" {
    ...
    ...
    execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.test_role.id
    ...
    ...
}

